# Getting lowest values in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

```
WITH test_data AS (
  SELECT 1 key, 1 a, 2 b FROM dual UNION ALL  --# Lowest a for key=1
  SELECT 1 key, 2 a, 1 b FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 key, 3 a, 3 b FROM dual UNION ALL  --# Lowest a for key=2, lowest b
  SELECT 2 key, 3 a, 4 b FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 key, 4 a, 5 b FROM dual
)
```

I'm trying to group by `key`, and retrieve the lowest `a` and the corresponding `b` (lowest `b` in case of ties), plus the SUM of its `b`s:

```
       KEY          A    FIRST_B      SUM_B
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          2          3
         2          3          3         12
```

I can realize this with a sub-select

```
SELECT key, MIN(a) AS a, first_b, SUM(b) AS sum_b
FROM (
  SELECT key, a, b,
         FIRST_VALUE(b) OVER (PARTITION BY key ORDER BY a, b) AS first_b
  FROM test_data
)
GROUP BY key, first_b
```

but I wonder if there is a way to avoid the sub-select, something like

```
SELECT key, a, SUM(b) AS sum_b,
       MIN( FIRST_VALUE(b) OVER (PARTITION BY key ORDER BY a, b) ) AS first_b
FROM test_data
GROUP BY key, a
```

which raises *ORA-30483: window  functions are not allowed here*

---

Thanks in advance, Peter

Comment: Is there are particular reason why you need to avoid a sub-select? Is what you have not performant enough?

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Right now, performance is not the issue. The query is rather complex, and re-typing all selected columns of the sub-select is something that I was trying to avoid for readability reasons.

Comment: Create a view for it or use alias.* you want all the columns. I doubt any funky solutions is going to be any more readable.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: In case you're interested, MikeyByCrikey provided the solution. Anyway, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for the [first](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm#i1000901)/last aggregate functions? Because of the `MIN` function, ordering by B on the first_b column should be redundant but that probably depends on how exactly you intend on using it.

```
WITH test_data AS (
  SELECT 1 key, 1 a, 2 b FROM dual UNION ALL  --# Lowest a for key=1
  SELECT 1 key, 2 a, 1 b FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 key, 3 a, 3 b FROM dual UNION ALL  --# Lowest a for key=2, lowest b
  SELECT 2 key, 3 a, 4 b FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 key, 4 a, 5 b FROM dual
)
select 
  key, 
  min(a) as a,
  min(b) keep (dense_rank first ORDER BY a, b) as first_b,
  SUM(b) AS sum_b
FROM test_data
GROUP BY key
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for :) I had used it before, but seem to have forgotten about it... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd probably also call the idea below a sub-select (or 2 subselects), but try it anyway.
Otherwise you're out of luck, as what you want requires that you perform two different group by aggregations, one on the key alone, and one on the key and on the a attribute.  And you cannot do two different group by aggregations in the same SQL statement.  So, you need at least two different SQL statements, which must then obviously be combined in some way.  And there is no way to combine two resultsets from two different SQL statments into one without treating one or the other (or both) as a sub-select of one kind or another)

```
   Select X.key, X.a, y.firstBm X.sum_b  
   From
    (SELECT tda.key, MIN(tda.a) a, 
        Min(case tdb.b) firstB, 
        SUM(tda.b) sum_b 
       FROM test_data tda
       Group By key) X
    Left Join
      (Select tda.key, a, 
        Min(b) firstB
       FROM test_data     
       Group By key, a) Y
    On Y.key = X.key  
       And Y.a = X.a
```